# How I can get specific value from HTTP method in FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post, http-get

My output is like this:

```
{
"scope": [],
"_id": "62413827f85e740dd8af749d",
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJpc3N1ZXIiLCJzdWIiOnsidXNlcklkIjoiNjI0MTM4MjdmODVlNzQwZGQ4YWY3NDlhIn0sImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ0MTM4M30.cNE32yojMlbohsOtgB2docCsZk8UPqEbPVTizV--rMs",
"user": {
    "_id": "62413827f85e740dd8af749a",
    "email": "ahmed@gmail.com",
    "password": "hello",
    "phone": "01723456789",
    "createdAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.334Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.334Z",
    "__v": 0
},
"createdAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.348Z",
"updatedAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.348Z",
"__v": 0
}
```

How can I get the value of "email" from "user" in flutter? I am using the following code.

```
http
      .post(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: {"Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"},
          body: jsonEncode(model))
      .then((value) {
    var access = jsonDecode(value.body);
```

Comment: After this make a model of the returned value. You can use the website JSON to Dart and paste your response in the field, give it a name and copy the generated code and paste it to your screen. Then Assign the `access` vairable to the model class you have generated. Then access the things you want to access using the name of the model class you have created through the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should use model . without using model it will help you

it's only a example how to get value from map

```
var apiResp = jsonDecode('''
    {
    "scope": [],
    "_id": "62413827f85e740dd8af749d",
    "access_token":
        "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJpc3N1ZXIiLCJzdWIiOnsidXNlcklkIjoiNjI0MTM4MjdmODVlNzQwZGQ4YWY3NDlhIn0sImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ0MTM4M30.cNE32yojMlbohsOtgB2docCsZk8UPqEbPVTizV--rMs",
    "user": {
      "_id": "62413827f85e740dd8af749a",
      "email": "ahmed@gmail.com",
      "password": "hello",
      "phone": "01723456789",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.334Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.334Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "createdAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.348Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.348Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
  ''');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('${apiResp['user']['email']}')),
```

here jsonDecode accept string value so i did this way

```
'''
    {
    "scope": [],
    "_id": "62413827f85e740dd8af749d",
    "access_token":
        "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJpc3N1ZXIiLCJzdWIiOnsidXNlcklkIjoiNjI0MTM4MjdmODVlNzQwZGQ4YWY3NDlhIn0sImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ0MTM4M30.cNE32yojMlbohsOtgB2docCsZk8UPqEbPVTizV--rMs",
    "user": {
      "_id": "62413827f85e740dd8af749a",
      "email": "ahmed@gmail.com",
      "password": "hello",
      "phone": "01723456789",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.334Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.334Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "createdAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.348Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-28T04:23:03.348Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
  '''
```